# How to configure a YML file in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I'm trying to configure my .yml but I get a null pointer exception always...

I have the following .yml:

```
search_files:
  csv:
    path: ./
    name: export_files_
    extension: .csv
```

I have the following pom configuration:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <argLine>-Dspring.config.location=file:${home}/config/application.yml</argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/application.yml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
```

And my implementation:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.victorprojects.utils.searchFiles.entity.bean.Result;

@Component
public class CSVUtils {

    @Value("${search_files.csv.path}")
    private static String PATH;
    
    @Value("${search_files.csv.name}")
    private static String NAME;
    
    @Value("${search_files.csv.extension}")
    private static String EXTENSION;

    public void createCsv(ArrayList<Result> results) {
       try {
            String fullPath = PATH.concat(NAME.concat(getCurrentDateTime().concat(EXTENSION)));
            FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fullPath, true);
            CSVPrinter csvPrinter = new CSVPrinter(fileWriter, CSVFormat.RFC4180);

            // HEADER
            csvPrinter.printRecord("Name", "Extension", "Size (Kb)", "Path");

            for (Result result : results) {
                // DATA
                csvPrinter.printRecord(result.getName(), result.getExtension(), result.getSize(), result.getPath());
            }

            csvPrinter.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

When I execute it, I get the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.core.env.Environment.getProperty(String)" because "this.env" is null
    at com.victorprojects.utils.searchFiles.utils.CSVUtils.createCsv(CSVUtils.java:28)
```

I have searched a lot of information in the Internet but I get the same error always...

How can I solve this?

### EDIT

I add a photo about my project structure:

[image]

You can download the project here:

- https://toffeesha.re/c/KELg3CB5

Comment: Can you add complete `CSUtils` class as a code snippet rather than an image?

Comment: Sure! I have updated the post!

Comment: According to your error msg, error is thrown by `createCsv` method (`CSVUtils.createCsv(CSVUtils.java:28)`). So include the implementation as well

Comment: You are right. Updated!

Comment: @Victor I should also include a complete stack trace :). How do you trigger CSVUtils.createCsv()? Could it be that spring initialization is not completed yet at the time the method is called?

Comment: @Victor is ${home} resolvable from the pom.xml ? might want to change it to full URL to confirm

Comment: @bLaXjack I think its a property in `pom.xml`

Comment: @ray I ilitialize it in my main.

Comment: @bLaXjack I replace ```${home}/config/application.yml``` for ```./config/application.yml``` but I get the follogin error: ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.isEmpty()" because "str" is null``` in this line ```String fullPath = PATH.concat(NAME.concat(getCurrentDateTime().concat(EXTENSION)));```

Comment: @Victor when you get this error? when you executing tests or runs spring boot application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem... I was initializing the CSVUtils constructor like this:

```
Utils utils = new Utils();
```

But I needed to initialize it this way:

```
@Autowired
Utils utils;
```

With the first way, I was initializing explicity the constructor, but I needed to do that with the Spring annotation to be able to use `@Value`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a setup of your project like:

```
projectName
 /config/application.yml
 /src/main/java/...
 /src/main/resources/...
 /src/test/java/...
 /src/test/resources/...
 pom.xml
```

When your project structure looks like the above, you don't need to provide `spring.config.location`, Spring will find your config-file.

But you could use: `-Dspring.config.location=config/application.yml`

---

Using `@Value` directly on a **static** String PROP_NAME is not allowed

So just use:

```java
 @Value("${search_files.csv.path}")
 private String PATH;
```

Or use constructor injection

```
@Component
public class CSVUtils {

    private String PATH;
    private String NAME;
    private String EXTENSION;

public CSVUtils(
    @Value("${search_files.csv.path}") String path, 
    @Value("${search_files.csv.name}") String name, 
    @Value("${search_files.csv.extension}") String extention){
     this.NAME=name;
     this.PATH=path;
     this.EXTENSION=extention;
}
```

or use a setter (here you can use *static* String PROP_NAME)

```
private static String PATH

@Value("${search_files.csv.path}")
public void setPath(String path) {
    CSVUtils.PATH = path;
}
```

Comment: I have removed the "static" annotation. But I get this error: ```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "String.isEmpty()" because "str" is null
 at java.base/java.lang.String.concat(String.java:1966)``` in this line ```in this line String fullPath = PATH.concat(NAME.concat(getCurrentDateTime().concat(EXTENSION)));``` because ```PATH```, ```NAME``` and ```EXTENSION``` are empty.

Comment: make sure your project is correctly setup (see answer)

Comment: note that `-Dspring.config.location=file:${home}/config/application.yml` will only be use with `surefire` (tests). But Spring will find `/config/application.yml` on a normal startup of your application.

Comment: I have the setup like that. So, should I change the line ```-Dspring.config.location=file:${home}/config/application.yml```???? What line should I put?

Comment: If you have a config folder with application.yml in your project-folder Spring will find it, you do not need to provide spring.config.location

Comment: It does not work. I have added a picture with my project structure.

Comment: @Victor still same error?

Comment: Yes... I have got the same error

Comment: here is a [demo](https://github.com/dirkdeyne/demo-logging-log4j2)? It has a test and an [endpoint](http://localhost:8080/csv) showing the csv-properties. I hope this helps

Comment: Nope, but you can download the project here: https://toffeesha.re/c/KELg3CB5

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class and add the configuration properties as:-

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "anyClass", locations = "file:config/abc.properties")
public class AnyClass{

    private String name;   

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

and in your main application class, provide annotation @EnableConfigurationProperties as below:-

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties({AnyClass.class)
public class SpringBootApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootApplication .class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can't use the ```location``` attribute... :(